# How to add bullets in featured snippet using structured data?

Tags: structured-data

I want to add bullets in featured snippet. When i search for '**gastric balloon**' in google it gives me featured snippet for this link **www.bariatric-surgery-source.com/gastric-balloon.html** as shows in below image :
PLEASE OPEN THIS IMAGE => https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MBoD.png .
I have marked those lines with red color i.e i want to make display them with bullets symbol instead of plain text. 
Someone suggest me that it could be possible with structured data but how?
And which code i have to write and where?

Answer (score 0):

You have done everything semantically, so I would make the assumption that Google will strip out any formatting, and apply their own.

Best thing you could do is mark it up with `ListItem` schema.

> An list item, e.g. a step in a checklist or how-to description.
>
> Source - https://schema.org/ListItem